# Align a fixed element on each elemetn of an unordered list

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a list `ul` with 3 fields: Name, Date, State. I want to allow Name and Date to overflow with a scrollbar, while the State stays at a fixed position (of the respective `li`) at the left top.

The following was the closest I could get to, but the `Closed` word gets cut on the borders, and the first and last element of the list, the `Closed` gets on another totally different position. Can I change only the `css`, or do I need to change the `html`

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a role="button">
            <h4>Name1</h4>
            <p>Date1</p>
            <span class="closed">Closed</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a role="button">
            <h4>Name2</h4>
            <p>Date2</p>
            <span class="closed">Closed</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.col ul
{
    padding-top:20px;
}

h4 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

p {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:mediumblue;
}

ul, li {
    list-style: none;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

    ul li {
        margin: 0em;
    }

        ul li a:hover, ul li a:focus {
            box-shadow: 10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
            transform: scale(1.25);
            position: relative;
            z-index: 5;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        ul li a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #000;
            background: #F8F4FF;
            display: block;
            height: 8em;
            width: 18em;
            padding: 1em;
            box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,.7);
            transition: transform .15s linear;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }
        ul li a p {
            margin-bottom:0;
        }

        ul li:nth-child(even) a{
            position: relative;
            background: #D4EDEB;
        }

        ul li:nth-child(3n) a {
            position: relative;
            /*top: -5px;*/
            background: #CFF2FF;
        }

.closed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: -15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: black;
    color: red;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -sand-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML structure was wrong. You cannot pu `h4` and `p` into `a`.

```css
.col ul
  {
    padding-top:20px;
}

h4 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

p {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:mediumblue;
}

ul, li {
    list-style: none;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

    ul li {
        margin: 0em;
    }

        ul li div:hover {
            box-shadow: 10px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
            transform: scale(1.25);
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        ul li div {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #000;
            background: #F8F4FF;
            height: 8em;
            width: 18em;
            padding: 1em;
            box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,.7);
            transition: transform .15s linear;
            overflow-y: auto;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }
        ul li div p {
            margin-bottom:0;
        }

        ul li:nth-child(even) a{
            position: relative;
            background: #D4EDEB;
        }

        ul li:nth-child(3n) div {
            position: relative;
            /*top: -5px;*/
            background: #CFF2FF;
        }

.closed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: -15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: black;
    color: red;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -sand-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            <h4>Name1</h4>
            <p>Date1</p>
            <span class="closed">Closed</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum dui lacus, luctus sit amet interdum porta, laoreet eget libero. Suspendisse in vehicula mauris. Nunc a enim et nibh malesuada malesuada. Aliquam fermentum odio commodo condimentum ultricies. Morbi vitae convallis velit, sed euismod arcu. </h4>
            <p>Date2</p>
            <span class="closed">Closed</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```